# How do I update an entity object in GridView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I am using `Entity Framework` with ASPX webform. In my `GridView`(GV) I make all my columns with `ItemTemplates` and `EditTemplates`. When in edit mode I can select a new value, but it does not update the record. In the GV I have a `DropDownList` which is set to a `EntityDataSource` that matches it's related table for that field. What steps do I need, what events do I need to handle? I have tried the `RowEditing` and `RowUpdating` events, but have no useful code thus far. If you want me to show you some bad code - just ask and I will be more than happy too. I just need some guidance on wiring this up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have an ADO.NET entity data model called - customerEntities which has one table Customers with 3 columns:

1. CustomerId
2. Name
3. Surname

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcancelingedit="gvCustomers_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowediting="gvCustomers_RowEditing" onrowupdating="gvCustomers_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="CustomerId">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerId") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Surname") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                BindCustomers();
        }

        private void BindCustomers()
        {
            customerEntities entityModel = new customerEntities();
            gvCustomers.DataSource = entityModel.Customers;
            gvCustomers.DataBind();
        }

        protected void gvCustomers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindCustomers();
        }

        protected void gvCustomers_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
            BindCustomers();
        }

        protected void gvCustomers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            int customerId = (int)gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
            TextBox txtName = (TextBox)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName");
            TextBox txtSurname = (TextBox)gvCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtSurname");

            customerEntities entityModel = new customerEntities();
            Customer customer = entityModel.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId).First();
            customer.Name = txtName.Text;
            customer.Surname = txtSurname.Text;
            entityModel.SaveChanges();

            gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
            BindCustomers();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Deni. All fields update on their own. The only fields I am having trouble with are the foreign key fields that are for the related tables. I will work on a variation of your work - running into a brick wall when trying to cast the DDL from the row even though I get the name right.

Comment: I even found this [blog](http://timwarddevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/bind-entity-to-rowdataitem.html) and tried to implement it without success.

Comment: Im also having troubles with the foreign key fields. Any success in solving that?